# React Router Redirect to component not redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need a simple redirect to a component but its not working not sure why. This is the code:

```
const HomePage = () => {

const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

const videoClicked = (video) => {
    return <Redirect to='/video' />
}

if(videos === []){
    return <div>Loading ...</div>
}

return (
    <div>
        {videos.map(video => (
            <div onClick={() => videoClicked(video)}>
                <VideoThumbnail video={video} />
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
}

export default HomePage
```

I have a useEffect in my HomePage function that I didnt include in this snippet that gives `videos` values. It works and when I onClick the div it calls `videoClicked` but the **redirect doesnt work.** 
This is my router:

```
  const App = () => {
     return (
        <HashRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/video" component={VideoPage} />
            <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
          </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
      )
    }
```

Also when I get this working is it possible to redirect to component and pass props thru it instead of just passing a string in the `to` tag.

Comment: That redirect jsx should be in the returned jsx of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a new state and redirect based on that:

```
const HomePage = () => {

    const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

    const videoClicked = (video) => {
        setClicked(true);
        // return <Redirect to='/video' />
    }

    if (videos === []) {
        return <div>Loading ...</div>
    }

    return (
        clicked ? <Redirect to={{
         pathname: '/video',
         state: { someData: 'test' }
        }} /> : (
            <div>
                {videos.map(video => (
                    <div onClick={() => videoClicked(video)}>
                        <VideoThumbnail video={video} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

and you can use `props.location.state.someData` in the component you're redirected to.

Comment: Thank you this worked! Is it possible in react router to send props to component in redirect?

Comment: @chrus54321 - Yes it's possible. I'll add that to my answer in a few mins.

Answer (score 1):

you can consider using History HTML5 instead :) simple and straightforward